# ssh : through router port forwards can mount sshfs but can't get a ssh terminal session

Tags: ssh, sshfs

`arch with openssh 9.7p1-1 ,sshfs 3.7.3-1`

This fstab entry works just fine.

```
stephen@999.99.99.99:/mnt/sda/srv /home/stephen/srv 
fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,
_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,port=2299,
identityfile=/home/stephen/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,
default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,exec 0 0
```

But this command times out

```
 ssh stephen@999.99.99.99 -p 2299
```

My assumption has been that `sshfs` requires `sshd` so the failure to create a ssh terminal session is due to something other than sshd down.

What could that be? Is it possible to fix remotely?